# Firebase Cloud Messaging not calling FirebaseInstanceId

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I just updated GCM to FCM according to this guide [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_your_gcmlistenerservice). The site says my service which extends FirebaseInstanceIdService will be called as soon as the token is generated. For some reason, my service is never called and `onTokenRefresh` is never executed.

My services are registered like this, according to the guide:

```
<service android:name=".fcm.FcmService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".fcm.InstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCEID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My service:

```
public class InstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "InstanceIdService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.e(TAG, "Got token: " + token);
    }
}
```

The LogCat doesn't say anything about missing configuration files or else, and I can see logs about FirebaseApp and a Log entry mentioning the token, but still my service is never called.

Do I need to start this service somewhere in my activity?
Am I doing something wrong? Can someone guide me in the correct direction?

EDIT: using `Log.e("TOKEN", "Token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());` correctly prints my token, so that means it was generated successfully. The service still doesn't get called...

EDIT 2: Changing INSTANCEID_EVENT to INSTANCE_ID_EVENT fixed the issue, although I had to reinstall the app. As I already released a beta version containing the new FCM, my beta testers won't be able to subscribe to the topics to reveice incoming messages. So how should I solve that?

Comment: For what it's worth, one doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) says the intent filter should be `INSTANCE_ID_EVENT` and another (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_the_android_manifest) says `INSTANCEID_EVENT`. Neither seem to be working for me -- I have the same issue as you.

Comment: @ZachRattner That did it for me, nice catch! Make sure you reinstall your app after the change.

Comment: I can confirm that INSTANCE_ID_EVENT worked for me but not INSTANCEID_EVENT

Comment: I can also confirm that changing INSTANCEID_EVENT to INSTANCE_ID_EVENT fixed the issue, although I had to reinstall the app. As I already released a beta version containing the new FCM, my beta testers won't be able to subscribe to the topics to reveice incoming messages. So how should I solve that?

Comment: @qwertz apart from "I told you so" regarding testing before pushing out releases, can you push a new beta test out? Presumably these are friendly beta testers so they'll understand if you tell them their current version is busted.

Comment: This is entirely a doc issue, a very unfortunate typo.  Sorry for the confusion!  FWIW the GCM doc is now updated with INSTANCE_ID_EVENT.

Comment: @ZachRattner yeah, should have tested it better... But updating the beta version still doesn't call the InstanceId service because the token has already been generated and is still valid, so no need to generate it again, right? Maybe I don't understand something correctly, but this is the way it should work isn't it?

Comment: @qwertz Could you change the package name in your test build to force a fresh install?

Comment: Should we call InstanceIdService class from somewhere else or onTokenRefresh() gets automatically called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks Endanke for figuring this out with me. It seems that the Firebase documentation is inconsistent. [One page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) says your intent filter in your manifest file should be `INSTANCE_ID_EVENT`, and [another](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_the_android_manifest) says `INSTANCEID_EVENT`.

You should use `INSTANCE_ID_EVENT`, and once you make the change, you'll need to completely uninstall and reinstall your app for the changes to kick in.

Comment: I already done this but it still doesn't call `onTokenRefresh()`

Comment: The think uninstall externally and re-run worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Is this answer still correct? Neither of the pages you linked include `INSTANCEID_EVENT` or `INSTANCE_ID_EVENT` in their text.

Answer (score 2):

FCM should be used as a replacement to GCM. In your case it looks like you have services for both FCM and GCM in your manifest. Try remove the gcm.GcmService, and only use the one that extends FirebaseInstanceId.

Comment: But where should I receive the incoming messages when I remove gcm.GcmService?

Comment: In your extension of FirebaseMessageService you would add a service for that as well

Comment: Sorry forgot to rename the GcmService, but it already extends FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling your app, you would only get the token generation callback when a new token is generated. If the app already had a token then no new token would be used. Uninstalling and reinstalling will force the generation of a new token.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure that your Firebase "MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java" file is directly under the package name tree "com.company"

Don't put them in the separate subpackage like "com.company.services". This is because your google-services.json will look for the files directly under "com.company" directory.

Add the following in your manifest application tag below meta tag (if any)

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

You will get your TOKEN on the public void onTokenRefresh() method

PS: Download and replace the latest google-services.json from your project console.

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of trial and error my issue was having   tools:node="replace" in my application tag...removing it solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and by uninstalling and reinstalling the app on the device `onTokenRefresh()` got called once. So I guess it changed from GCM where it got called often to just getting called once when there actually is no token.

Answer (score 0):

I've different build variants in my project and I've the following problem:

From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites

> Note: If you have multiple build variants with different package names defined, each app must be added to your project in Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the date of your phone! I once had a difference of 5-7 days! Fixing the day and reinstalling the app fixed this!

Answer (score 0):

What 'Firebase Cloud Messaging' wants is:

- Implement a derived class (*MyFirebaseInstanceIdService*) from
  *FirebaseInstanceIdService*.
- Implement the override *onTokenRefresh* to handle an update on the
  token for the device.
- In the AndroidManifest.xml reference the 'derived' class prefixed
  with a ".".

*MyFirebaseInstanceIdService* is a 'suggested' name. I personally prefer to prefix such derived classes with an acronym or name that I use throughout the App.

Answer (score 0):

`onTokenRefresh()` will call only one time.when your app is install first time, if you want to access token from other activity you have to call this method:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId().getToken();
```

Answer (score -1):

just change the INSTANCE_ID_EVENT  to INSTANCEID_EVENT .it worked for me